# To read/set a user screensaver on Windows, do I need to use system registry or SystemParametersInfo API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, screensaver

There seems to be two methods of setting and getting a user screensaver parameters on a Windows platform:

1: Via the SystemParametersInfo() API:

```
//To read
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVEACTIVE, 0, &bScreensaverAcrtive, NULL);
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT, 0, &nScreensaverTimeout, NULL);
//No API to get the screensaver file used

//To set
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE, 0, bScreensaverAcrtive, NULL);
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT, 0, nScreensaverTimeout, NULL);
//No API to change the screensaver file
```

2: Through the system registry keys:

```
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop - "ScreenSaveActive"
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop - "ScreenSaveTimeOut"
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop - "SCRNSAVE.EXE"
```

But since there're two competing methods that seem to do the same, what is the recommended way to use?

PS. I highly favor method #2 (or writing directly into registry) due to the following reasons:

A. If you read the explanation of a bug in the [SPI_GETSCREENSAVEACTIVE flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you'll see that MS themselves [recommend](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318781) to use registry.

B. If you read the documentation for the [SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flags, there's this mystical line that says, "*If the machine has entered power saving mode or system lock state, an ERROR_OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS exception occurs.*" I first ignored this situation until it actually started happening on my test installation of Windows 8. This is the most asinine error, I should tell you. There's absolutely no graceful way of interpreting what it means or do any workaround (except, writing directly into the registry.)

Comment: Well, it seems you've already answered your own question - if the API is buggy, use the registry, of course.

Comment: I want to hear if anyone else stopped using SystemParametersInfo() API for the purpose of working with a screensaver. That's the only reason I posted.

Comment: Well, here's [some arguments for using the API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/09/390706.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Although it's a 7 year old article...

Comment: @ahmd0: But the "bug" you refer to is 12 years old !

Comment: @MSalters: No, it's present in Windows 7. That article is not updated. Read documentation for the SPI_GETSCREENSAVEACTIVE flag.

Answer (score 3):

**Use the API.** Asking that is like asking if you should wait for the traffic light to turn green before crossing the road. I won't call the cops if I see you crossing at red, but if you ask me, I'll tell you you have to wait. And *you* are the one taking the risk of bad things happening.

---

The API is documented, the registry locations are not. Microsoft is in no obligation to preserve the registry locations or their functionality.

The SPI_GETSCREENSAVEACTIVE flag affects Windows 2000. If you support Windows 2000 as a target platform, I would apply the registry read to that version only (`OSVERSIONINFO.dwMajor=5`, `.dwMinor=0`)

`ERROR_OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS` I'd try to figure out under what circumstances this happens (e.g. screensaver already active, or system about to enter a power saving state).

Generally, I'd find it questionable if activating / deactivating the screensaver is not at least related to a user action, in which case the system should be ready to accept a change.

---

**What are you trying to achieve?** Why do you need to modify screensaver activity? Maybe there's some better method to achieve your goal

Comment: ERROR_OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS happens if say, I have two or more logged in user sessions. If I don't log back into some of them (hard to judge for how long) and try to change the screensaver parameter using SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT) in them, I get that error. This doesn't happen on Windows 7 or earlier.

Comment: So *why* do you want to change screensaver setting?

Answer (score 1):

Use the API. The registry format changes often.

As for the power state changes, screen savers are really a 20th century feature. Laptops turn off the screen entirely, for obvious reasons. In that power saving state `SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE` obviously should fail. Not a lot of interpreting to do.

So, check for `GUID_VIDEO_POWERDOWN_TIMEOUT` first.

*edit*

I just realized that Group Policy screensavers are also unlikely to be in the registry, and certainly would override `HKCU`. Not a real issue for Windows 2000, of course, but today the API method would be even more advisable. Of course, do realize that this is just another reason why `SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE` may return an error. Still an improvement over the registry approach, which fails silently in the presence of Group Policy.

Comment: This is not for Windows 2000. All those bugs exist in Windows 7 and 8 as I'm testing it now. As the GPO goes, then yes, the API will fail but with a different error code.

Answer (score 0):

"To set" above is incorrect. It should be:

```
//To set
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE, bScreensaverAcrtive, NULL, NULL);
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT, nScreensaverTimeout, NULL, NULL);
```